# Copy datas from one field of an array to another field of an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I use a component (ZOO) with the CMS Joomla to create articles.

The articles have different fields (title, subtitle, text, links, etc.) and the datas are stored in database in a column named "elements" like this :

```
{

    "b7b99652-839b-4171-8b4b-54a20415e459":  {
        "0":  {
            "value": "datas i want to copy"
        }
    },
    "8e3a883d-ab97-4091-869e-6189c0450c85":  {
        "0":  {
            "value": "here i want to record the datas i want to copy",
            "text": "",
            "target": "1",
            "custom_title": "",
            "rel": ""
        }
    }
}
```

[image: phpMyAdmin]

I would like to copy the value of b7b99652-839b-4171-8b4b-54a20415e459 inside the value of 8e3a883d-ab97-4091-869e-6189c0450c85

I know how to copy datas from one column to another with MySQL but here in don’t know how to do this.

I can't do it manually because i have more than 400 entries like this.

Comment: that's json. you don't deal with json. you decode the json to a native structure (e.g. php array/object), then deal with the data there.

Comment: @MarcB ok, i see. So there is nothing to do with phpMyAdmin ? My question's title is also wrong ?

Comment: you could TRY to do the updates via mysql, but mysql knows NOTHING about json - you'd be doing pure string operations, and probably end up with corrupt json. it's FAR easier to pull the json into client-side code (e.g. php) and do the manipulation there. and nitpicking: phpmyadmin is a management tool for mysql. it is NOT a database.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks. I know phpmyadmin is a management tool for mysq. I use it often to make simple operation. Sorry if it was unclear. So i will follow your advice and use php. About my title, can we talk about an array here or not at all ? I don't how how to call  this data organisation.

Comment: it's just nested objects. pull it into php, `json_decode()` it, then `var_dump()` the decoded structure. that'll show you the "path" you need to take to access the various bits.